# Adding another argument to my discord.py command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add an additional argument to this mute command I have made for my discord.py bot but I'm getting a SyntaxError and have been having trouble understanding the syntax for what I'm trying to do.

Here is the part of my program that is relevant to my issue:

```
#Tempmute Command
@bot.command(name='tempmute')
@commands.has_role('Moderator' or 'Admin')
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member,time):
    #Retrieves the amount of time the user should be muted for
    muted_role=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600,"d":86400}
    tempmute= int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]

    #Deletes invocation and adds muted role to target, sends embed confirming user has been delete THEN deletes embed
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    #Notifies target was muted through sending a direct message
    notify = discord.Embed(title="Muted", description=f" You have been muted in {member.guild.name}.",colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    #Catches an exception if the direct message fails to send
    try:
        await member.send(notify)
    except Exception as e:
        embedFail = discord.Embed(description= f" **{ctx.author.mention}, I was unable to notify this user they were muted**", color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embedFail, delete_after=5)
     embed = discord.Embed(description= f"✅ **{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator} has been muted successfully", color=discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5)

    #Removes role after given time
    await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
    await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
```

This line defines my arguments for my asynchronous function 'mute'

```
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member,time):
```

When I try to add an additional argument 'reason' I run into a SyntaxError

```
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member,time,reason):
```

I should also note when adding the additional argument, I'm also changing my embedded message the bot displays to add the reason given from the author as well. See this changed line here:

```
embed = discord.Embed(description= f"✅ **{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator} has been muted successfully for", reason, color=discord.Color.green())
```

The error I get is: SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

If someone could please explain why I'm not able to simply add this additional piece to my mute command I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Also if you have any additional suggestions for improving the use of this command please feel free leave a comment noting your suggestion as well. (Please take into consideration though I'm new to Python and discord.py so I may need a detailed explanation or example as to what you're suggesting I improve in my code.)

Answer (score 0):

> The error I get is: SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Rather than:

```
...muted successfully for", reason, color=...
```

try a simple `reason=reason` kwarg call:

```
...muted successfully for", reason=reason, color=...
```

---

The motivation for this diagnostic
is to improve code clarity at the
call site.
The caller may use "short" positional
args

```
f(a, b, c)
```

but then once you start using keywords,
you should keep using them so it's
clear which value gets substituted
for which formal parameter.

```
f(a, b, c, d=4, e=5, f=6, g=g, h=h)
```

Comment: When attempting this solution, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Embed.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reason'`

See here:

`async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member,time,reason):`

and

`notify = discord.Embed(title="Muted", description=f" You have been muted in {member.guild.name} for",reason=reason,colour=discord.Colour.red())`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that API, and you didn't cite a ReadTheDocs url. In particular, I wasn't certain the name of the formal parameter matched the identifier name you chose: "reason". Apparently it has some other name. I encourage you to cite the documentation and to try a revised kwarg name.

Comment: Did you perhaps have in mind ... `,description=reason,` ... ? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.title

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `color=discord.Color.green()` AFTER reason. This is because `reason` is a positional argument, so if you put it before the `color`, a named argument, python will get confused.

Also, a small side note is that `@commands.has_role('Moderator' or 'Admin')` is not going to work. `or` is a boolean operator, so it is used for just `True` and `False`. Use `@commands.has_any_role('Moderator', 'Admin')` to check if they have either the Moderator or Admin role.